# AdView doesn't appear at the bottom of the app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, adview

I am trying to put an AdView at the bottom of my app. However, when I test my app, I don't see the ad, nor the AdView.

In my MainActivity, I am replacing the 2 FrameLayouts with 2 fragments. So the AdView should appear after the third fragment.

Here's my main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/layout_id"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="app_id"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main_activity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("5554:Perfect_One")
        .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        myContext = this;

        fragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();

        Fragment frag = new SortFeature();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, frag);
        ft.commit();

        Fragment frag2 = new CardListView();
        FragmentTransaction ft2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft2.replace(R.id.fragment_content2, frag2);
        ft2.commit();
```

Here's the layout used by the CardListView fragment.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:background="@drawable/background" />
```

Here's my logcat:

```
09-08 21:22:29.578: I/Ads(2050): JS: Creating Application Cache with manifest http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)

09-08 21:22:29.588: I/chromium(2050): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Creating Application Cache with manifest http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)

09-08 21:22:29.618: I/Ads(2050): JS: Application Cache Checking event (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)

09-08 21:22:49.629: W/Ads(2050): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 320x0 dp.
```

Comment: Post some stack trace, are you getting message like "Not enough space to show ads"?

Comment: I would like to tell you. Unfortunately, my logcat isn't working at this moment. I am restarting eclipse and the emulator in order to make it work again.

Comment: I have posted my logcat. I see that there is not enough space for the ad to be shown. However, I can't figure out a way to make more room for it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to make it work. The problem was that there was not enough space for the ad to be shown.

The height of my CardListView fragment was 500dp. It was too much. I reduced it to 300dp and I can now see my Adview proprely.

Comment: You have to tweak this dimension value for multiple screen size in order for it to work properly, but the chances you are going to miss some screen size is 100%. My suggestion is you change the 2nd fragment to `layout_height="0dp"` and set `layout_weight="1"` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to place the AdView in front of the second fragment. So that the Adview takes up a small portion of the second fragment ?

Comment: FrameLayout itself will allow you to overlay one view over another, but the top view may cover part of the bottom view in this case. Just put your 2nd fragment and AdView into another LinearLayout if you want to have both shown together without overlapping.